# What could be causing low pressure in my new faucet, a Moen 87690SRS?

Tags: plumbing

UPDATE: This ended up being a known issue with this model's diverter. They are sending a replacement part.

---

I've a newly installed Moen 87690SRS faucet whose pressure is really low compared to the old faucet.  The separate sprayer has a good amount of pressure. A new cartridge did not fix the lower pressure faucet problem.

What else should we try to do in order to increase the pressure?

Comment: This ended up being a known issue with this model's diverter. They are sending a replacement part. Thank you for the responses though!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes replacing fixtures will break loose crud that will end up in 1 of 3 usual places:

1. At the shut off valve/connection hose
2. Inside the cartridge
3. At the aerator screen

   Start at the aerator, its the easiest to check.  Make a water check with the aerator off.  You can flush out the aerator in reverse at that time.  Be careful to reassemble in the reverse order, you wouldn't want to leave the restrictor plate off accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

The Moen 87690SRS faucet is rated at a flow rate of 2.2 gpm (gallons per minute). [See the specs here.](http://www.homedepot.com/p/MOEN-Banbury-Single-Handle-Side-Sprayer-Kitchen-Faucet-in-Spot-Resist-Stainless-87690SRS/202696365#specifications)

[image]

You may want to test out the actual flow rate in the sink through measurement. If it comes in close to the flow rate of 2.2 gpm then the only way you are going to see a more energetic stream of water in this sink is to look for another model with a higher gpm rating.

Note that this model of faucet does not have an adjustable flow rate but some other fancier models may have that feature.

Comment: 2.2gpm is the max. allowed flow rate according to model plumbing codes in the US, so finding a higher flow in the US could be difficult. The reasoning for this restriction is to conserve water and energy, a laudable goal. Some fixtures, especially cheaper ones, achieve this with a restrictor plate above the aerator which is easily removed, defeating the conservation intent.